# What is the meaning of making the differential of an integral the argument of a function?

Tags: integration

I've seen a notation in a paper amounting to $$\int f(x) g(dx).$$

That is, the differential is used as the argument of a function.

My understanding is that Riemann integrals do not allow such notation. I assume this is informal shorthand for a more standard type of integral. What is its meaning?

One guess for such meaning is to apply a variable transformation $y = g(x)$ and have the above equivalent to
$$\int f(g^{-1}(y))dy,$$

Is that correct?

PS: this seems very related to [What is the meaning of writing the differential inside of a function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3974087/what-is-the-meaning-of-writing-the-differential-inside-of-a-function) but both that question and answer seem quite more complicated than what I am asking here.

Comment: Note: It's a generalization of the Riemann integral called the [Riemann-Stieltjes integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral#Formal_definition)

Comment: Stieltjes integral was my first thought too, but it doesn't look right.  For those it is supposed to be dG(x) or some such, I thought.  I can't tell what this is supposed to mean.

Comment: That is not the notation of a Riemann-Stieltjes integral.